# How use std::multiset with multiple comparator function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

Good afternoon, I have a C++ class `Range` which implements a `operator <` for use by   `std::multiset<Range> ranges_type`.

Since the multiset constructor don't specify a a custom comparator functor, it uses the `std::less operator <`.

However, I need to use a second comparator functor for `std::multiset ranges_type`. Specifically, I would specify a second comparator: 
`std::multiset<Range, PointerCompare>` where `struct PointerCompare` looks this :

```
struct PointerCompare{
   bool operator()(const Range& a, const Range& b) const {
         return (a.mPtr == b.mPtr)
   }
```

Is it possible to use `std:multiset` with multiple comparator functions or is there a workaround? Thank you

The class `Range` looks this:

```
class Range { 
     public:   
         explicit Range(int item){ 
            mLow = item;
            mHigh = item;
            mPtr  = 0;
         }
         Range(int low, int high, char* ptr = 0,char* mapptr = 0){ 
            mLow = low;
            mHigh = high;
            mPtr  = ptr;

         }
         Range(void){  
            mLow = 0;
            mHigh = 0;
            mPtr  = 0;

         }

         Range(const Range& r):
            mLow(r.mLow),
            mHigh(r.mHigh),
            mPtr(r.mPtr)
         {

         }


         bool operator==(const Range& rhs) const{
             return (mLow <= rhs.mLow && mHigh >= rhs.mHigh);
         }
         bool operator<(const Range& rhs) const{               
            return mHigh < rhs.mHigh;      
         } 
         int low() const { return mLow; }   
         int high() const { return mHigh; }
         char* getPtr() const { return mPtr; }
     private:   
         int mLow;   
         int mHigh; 
         char* mPtr;
}; // class Range
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would want *multiple* comparators.  How would that make sense?  What is wrong with `std::multiset<Range, PointerCompare>`?

Comment: Also, please be careful with your formatting.  You should format code snippets with the "{}" button.  I already did this for you, but you've edited your question and broken it all again!

Comment: Oli Charlesworth: I need to use two comparators because I use: std::multiset<Range>::const_iterator iter = ranges_type.lower_bound(Range(n)); if(iter == ranges_type.end() || iter->low() > n){ found = false;} else{ curr = *iter; found = true; }

Comment: @Frank: I'm not sure I understand.  Are you saying that you want to be able to iterate through your multiset in different sorted orders?  This is not possible (so you'd need to find a different data structure).  If that's not what you want, then what you are doing is correct; i.e. providing a custom comparator as a template argument.

Comment: Oli Charlesworth: I need to use two comparators because I use: std::multiset<Range>::const_iterator iter = ranges_type.lower_bound(Range(n)); if(iter == ranges_type.end() || iter->low() > n){ found = false;} else{ curr = *iter; found = true; }. I need to use a 2nd comparator like this std::multiset<Range>::iterator iter = find(range_types.begin(), ranges_type.end(),curr); range__type.erase(iter) . Thank you . I apologize for breaking your edit.

Comment: @Frank: In that case, you will need to use a different data structure, as suggested in @wheaties' answer...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, if we are to provide 2 custom comparator as template argument, how we do this with one instance of std::multiset<Range> ranges_type. Could we use a assignment operator/copy constructor like this: ranges_type = std::multiset<Range,PointerCompare>. Thank you.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, Could you please tell me where I could find @wheaties answer about different data structures? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds almost like you'd be better if you used something from [Boost::MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) rather than trying to force several different comparator functions onto a std::multiset.  They have a bunch of different container types ([see here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/index.html).)  In particular I'd look at the [ordered_indices](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/ord_indices.html) versions.

Comment: @wheaties, Thank you for your answer. We can't use Boost because we don't haven't paid for the latest Solaris UNIX, IBM AIX or HPUX licenses. In order to use a Boost distribution, we need to have a the latest Solaris UNIX, IAM AIX and HPUX licenses. Is there a link to a custom C++ class which implements a minimal version of ordered_indices? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: Since when does one need to pay for something in order to use Boost?

Comment: @Oli Charlewsworth, It is correct that we not need to pay any something in Boost. However, I tried using Boost::regex in an project last year and the Solaris, IBM AIX and HPUX compilers generated numerous compiler errors with the Boost Code, We were told that the Boost compiler errors would go away if purchased the latest UNIX licenses. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank who told you that?  The vendor?  Some libraries won't work with older compilers, some will.  You have to read the documentation as most libraries are rather explicit with what will/won't work.  That said, I believe this is one of those libraries that should work.

Comment: @wheaties, The last time we purchased UNIX Licenses for Solaris, IBM AIX and HP UX was in 2005/2006. Boost has changed substantially since then. That is why we got all the UNIX compiler errors when we tried building the boost regex library. Thank you

Comment: @wheaties, I just accepted your answer. Could you please where we could find an example of how to use Boost ordered_indices container to implement multiple comparator functions? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would expect the boost version [from ~2006](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) to work with a ~2006 C++ implementation. Those old versions are still available

Answer (score 1):

I may have found a workaround for multiple comparator functions: Here it is:

Range targetRange = Range(PreviousNCopy,PreviousN, TmpPrevMapPtr);

bool Found = std::binary_search( ranges_type.begin(), ranges_type.end(), 
   targetRange, MyComparator() );

where:  MyComparator is a struct : 
struct MyComparator {
    bool operator () ( const Range& d1, const Range& d2 ) const
    {
        return d1.getPtr() < d2.getPtr();
    } 
};

std::binary_search take o(log n) time but the std::multiset ranges_type must always remain sorted. Thank you.